# Azure Cognitive Search usage monitoring

Tags: azure, azure-functions, grafana, azure-cognitive-search, azure-monitoring

I have multiple Azure Cognitive Search services, distributed among different subscriptions. I would like to monitor the usage of each service, what should include:

- storage: current/quota
- no. indexes: current/quota
- no. indexers: current/quota
- no. data sources: current/quota

as I can access them through Overview/Usage pane in Azure portal or through Management RestAPI.

[image: Azure Cognitive Search usage details]

I would like to push this data to Grafana monitoring but I have some problems around that:

- I am not able to fetch this type of data from Metrics
- diagnostic settings does not allow to export this type of data (only metrics and operation logs)

Since it's possible to access the usage data through RestAPI I was thinking about creating Function App, that will ping each search service to collect the data and then push it to Log Analytics, which I can then use in Grafana. Maybe I can have one function app per subscription and use RBAC to grant access to search services, but still I don't like to have one app that have access to multiple search services.

How can I push the data from RestAPI to Log Analytics/Grafana other than using a function app?

Answer (score 1):

As of now, it looks like there is no other option other than pushing this data via additional function to your destination.